# Trying to manipulate class attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Trying to remove/add class attribute to li so that correct one is active when clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/cyberpuunk/D2RLR/2372/

```
<div class="container">        
          <div class="span8">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs gallery-nav">
                <li class="active">
                  <a href="#"<strong>All</strong></a>
                </li>
             <li><a href="#"><strong>link1</strong></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><strong>link2</strong></a></li>
             </ul>
              </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="span12">
           <div class="page1">qwer</div>
            <div class="page1">asdf</div>
            <div class="page1">zxcv</div>
       </div>  
    </div>    
</div>
```

```
$('.page1:gt(0)').hide();

$('ul.gallery-nav li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var liIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.page1').hide().eq(liIndex).show();
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    eq(liIndex).addClass("active");
}); // end click
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.gallery-nav li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.page1').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
    $('ul.gallery-nav li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2373/)

You had a syntax error at

```
eq(liIndex).addClass("active");
```

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is a jQuery object method and not a function that you can on its own. That could be fixed by using `$('ul.gallery-nav li').eq(liIndex).addClass("active");` BUT there would would be still a logic flaw:

```
$(this).removeClass("active");
```

You're supposed to `add` instead of `remove` the class, as `this` references the clicked `li` and not the whole group of list items which you're attaching the handler to. With that said, the fixed version of your code is:

```
    $('ul.gallery-nav li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
//as $(this) references the clicked li, you don't need $('ul.gallery-nav li').eq(liIndex)
```

Answer (score 2):

For an odd reason you are coding `$(this).removeClass('active')`, note that you should first create a jQuery object and then call `eq` method, try the following.

```
$('ul.gallery-nav li').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     var liIndex = $(this).index();
     $('.page1').hide().eq(liIndex).show();
     $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54Xdr/

Comment: +1 for the `siblings`, I always forget to use it for these cases. `=]`